# "Open declaration" (F3) doesn't work in Facelets files of some projects

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven, jboss, facelets

I have installed JBoss tools plugin in my Eclipse. When pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> ("Open Declaration") in an EL expression of a Facelets file like

```html
<h:inputText value="#{sectionSearchController.sectionCode}" />
```

then Eclipse will navigate to the corresponding class/method. This works fine in some projects, but in other projects it doesn't work at all. I don't understand why. How do I configure the project to get it to work? I'm using Maven to manage my projects.

Answer (score 1):

The project's JSF facet has to be enabled in order to enable JBoss JSF tools.

[image]

Comment: Its already enabled but also navigation will not work
I think thats may because of some Maven configurations
@BaluC

Comment: The above should also work for Mavenized projects. What type of project is it exactly?